# exponents and negative numbers

Tags: r

I do not know if other R users have found the following problem.

Within R I do the folowing operation:

```
> (3/-2)^(1/3)
[1] NaN
```

I obtain a `NaN` result.

I the similar way if I set:

```
> w<-(3/-2)
> g<-1/3
> w^g
[1] NaN
```

However, if I do:

```
> 3/-2
[1] -1.5
> -1.5^(1/3)
[1] -1.144714
```

Is there anybody that can explain this contradiction?

Answer (score 3):

Where do you see a problem? `-1.5^(1/3)` is not the same as `(-1.5)^(1/3)`. If you have basic maths education you shouldn't expect these to be the same.

Read `help("Syntax")` to learn that `^` has higher precedence than `-` in R.

Answer (score 1):

Begin by doing `(3/2)^(1/3)` and after add "`-`" 
you can't calculate a cube root of a negative number !

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the mathematical definition of exponentiation. For the continuous real exponentiation operator, you are not allowed to have a negative base.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the answer you can do the computation over the complex numbers, i.e. get the cube root of `-1.5+0i`:

```
complex(real=-1.5,im=0)^(1/3)
## [1] 0.5723571+0.9913516i
```

This is actually only one of three complex roots of `x^3+1.5==0`:

```
polyroot(c(1.5,0,0,1))
[1]  0.5723571+0.9913516i -1.1447142+0.0000000i  0.5723571-0.9913516i
```

but the other answers probably come closer to addressing your real question.